# Fullcalendar.io CSS not working in rails 6 app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I am building a RoR app with the 6.0.2 version of rails.
I need to use Fullcalendar.io for my project:

So far did:

```
yarn add @fullcalendar/core @fullcalendar/daygrid @fullcalendar/list
```

In my application.js file:

```
window.Calendar = require("@fullcalendar/core").Calendar;
window.dayGridPlugin = require("@fullcalendar/daygrid").default;
window.listPlugin = require("@fullcalendar/list").default;
```

In my pages.scss file:

```
@import '@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
@import '@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
@import '@fullcalendar/list/main.css';
```

In my calendar.html.erb page:

```
<section class="section">
  <div class="container m-t-20">
    <div id="calendar"></div>
  </div>
</section>



<script>

  $(function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        right: 'dayGridMonth, listMonth'
      },

      plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, listPlugin ],
      defaultView: 'dayGridMonth'
    });

    calendar.render();
  });
</script>
```

After lauching the application, i can see in the Calendar page, dates and informations from the calendar but there is no CSS.

Which step i am missing ? 
Many thanks

Comment: Your code works fine for me. So is that your entire `calendar.html.erb`? Is that served within a template that includes `application.js`?

Comment: @Codebling yes the appliction.js is in app/javascript/packs folder, so i don't why the calendar is working fine but i can't get the css of it

Comment: @Thomas sorry I did not see that only CSS was not working

Comment: What css compressor are you using? `config.assets.css_compressor = ???`

Comment: @Codebling it is webpack, so not sure how the path should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution by adding:

**In package.json**

```
"moment": "^2.29.1"
```

**and in app/javascript/packs/application.js**

```
import moment from 'moment'
window.moment = moment
```

Answer (score 5):

Depending on whether you're using Webpack or if you're just using a CSS compressor, you might not be able to just import the CSS by referencing the package.

For example `@import '@fullcalendar/core/main.css';` references the package `@fullcalendar/core` in your `node_modules` folder, but some CSS processors aren't configured to look in `node_modules`.

If they are, then a simple path like this will work:

```
@import 'node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
@import 'node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
@import 'node_modules/@fullcalendar/list/main.css';
```

If they are not, you'll need to use a relative path:

```
@import '../node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
@import '../node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
@import '../node_modules/@fullcalendar/list/main.css';
```

You may have to alter the path in the example above for your specific setup. The path to `node_modules` should be relative to your CSS files.

Comment: I tried to change the path but it is showing me the same

Comment: @Tomas are there errors during webpack or any errors in dev console?

Comment: no i cannot see anything except this: 
  ↳ app/views/pages/calendar.html.erb:10
  Rendered pages/calendar.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 9.0ms | Allocations: 1630)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do

Comment: @Tomas I'm not sure what is happening, then. In dev tools, you should check if your CSS is loaded. If it is, check to see if the FullCalendar CSS is loaded, as well.

Comment: I checked in the console, the css is loaded but not FullCalendar Css

Comment: @Thomas Did you use the correct relative path? Try `node_modules/` (module reference) and `../node_modules/` (relative path, replace `..` with whatever the relative path is in your case.

Comment: yes i tried with both, and none are actually working

Comment: @Tomas if your relative path is correct and you see no errors during webpack, I am really not sure why it is not working. Other code with the same setup works, so I am not sure why yours might be different. Try running Webpack by itself (not in dev mode, which will incrementally repack) to be sure there are no errors, check the `@fullcalendar/core/main.css` actually exists in your node_modules, and check your relative path again.

Comment: According to this source https://dev.to/vvo/a-rails-6-setup-guide-for-2019-and-2020-hf5#webpacker-usage
I should be using 

 <%= stylesheet_pack_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track": "reload" %>

instead of 

 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track": "reload" %>

But when i do, then absolutely nothing is charging in terms of css. I am quite lost with those changes in rails 6

Comment: Also to answer you, i did checked in node_modules the files, and when running webpacker it showed me 'compiled successfully'

Comment: @Tomas sorry you're still having problems! I don't know why

Comment: Hi @Tomas. Did you solved your issue ? I am getting the same using both rails 6.0.2.2 and fullcalendar 4.4.0

Comment: @ogs Hi, no i didn't. Did you find something ? From my side i guess its turbolinks creating the problem but i can't find the solution

Answer (score 4):

Here is what works for me:

I use webpacker with Rails 6.0.3.

1. '/app/javascript/packs/application.js':

```js
require("fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js")
```

2. '/app/javascript/fullcalender/fullcalendar.js' (This is a custom folder working together with the `require in 1`):

```js
import { Calendar } from "@fullcalendar/core";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";


document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ dayGridPlugin ],
    height: "parent",

  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

3. '/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.scss':

```css
@import '@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
@import '@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
```

4. 'html.erb'

```html
<section class="section">
   <div id="calendar"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi @printfinn
Got the issue, as described by the author, even using the solution you gave.
I do not understand why we are getting that CSS issue

Comment: @ogs Hi! Is there any error messages from the browser? Or from Rails? Can you share the code you're using? Did you notice the `turbolinks:load` part?